# Magmi v0.7.21 is running prior/old file

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I started to use a remote import mode from an external ftp, it was working for a few days then doesn't matter what I do when trying to run the remote profile it runs an old file from a few days ago. I don't know where this file is. I re-create the profile with a new name and the same thing. Thank you.

Comment: could you try running the latest magmi git master ? (install it aside the current 0.7.21 , in another directory, and copy the profiles directory (all directories under magmi/conf dir) under the new magmi install conf directory)

Comment: Hi, after accessing the new magmi there is an error below the copy & switch profile:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/magmi-git-master/magmi/plugins/5b5/general/atrributescleanup/attributescleanup.php on line 94

Comment: Can you instruct me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your PHP version to 5.4+ as Magmi is not compatible with PHP < 5.4.